# emacsclient GUI has small fonts

Tags: emacsclient, daemon

Recently I updated Emacs to the newest version (26.2) which comes with new daemon functionality and Emacs server in combination with Systemd (Manjaro here).

Previously there were no issues with setting a server, but now I've got no idea what is going on.

I did what is recommended [here (EmacsWiki)](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsAsDaemon#toc2) and [here (StackExchange)](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/46774/24130) so I have an `emacs.service` file and set `systemctl --user enable emacs` and 
`systemctl --user start emacs` but my `emacsclient` GUI comes out **shrunk**.

[image: screenshot of Emacs with tiny text]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How have you configured your fonts in Emacs?

Comment: @DoMiNeLa10 (set-face-attribute 'default nil :font "SF Mono-14")
(set-frame-font "SF Mono" nil t)

Comment: Try something like `(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(font . "SF Mono-14"))`

Comment: Yeah, now the font is being displayed properly, but the hiding of the `(menu-bar-mode -1)`, `(tool-bar-mode -1)` and `(scroll-bar-mode -1)` doesn't work

Comment: Can you try evaluating these manually once Emacs has loaded?

Comment: Evaluating them manually works. I've actually removed the `(when (window-system) ...)` formula and now everything works properly. Thank you!

Comment: This is one of the quirks of running Emacs as a server. If you're worried about getting errors in Emacs compiled without GUI support with things like scrollbars, this code might work. I haven't tested it in a while though, and I wrote it when I was messing with elisp just a little bit too much: https://github.com/DoMiNeLa10/.emacs.d/blob/master/config/my-customization.el#L54-L59

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The things that I did on the @DoMiNeLa10's advice:

1. Set

```
(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(font . "SF Mono-14"))
```

instead of

```
(set-face-attribute 'default nil :font "SF Mono-14")
(set-frame-font "SF Mono" nil t)
```

2. By playing around with evaluating `(menu-bar-mode -1)`, `(tool-bar-mode -1)` and `(scroll-bar-mode -1)` I just found out that it works if I remove the formulae of

```
(when (window-system)
  ;; Then evaluate the menu-bar, tool-bar, scroll bar etc. disabling
  )
```

And the issue is gone.